# Deleting data from logs directory (NOT kafka-logs) in Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka

We started using kafka from 14 months.  Retention is 7 days. We have 2 folders ( `kafka-logs`, `logs`).

One of them has 7 days data ( `kafka-logs`) but the other has 14 months data ( `logs`)

**1.** 
Here is the setting in `server.xml`

```
log.dirs=/install/kafka-logs
```

**kafka-logs** has only 7 days daya. ( Our Retention is 7 days. )

**2. 
Here is another folder:**

```
/install/kafka_2.10-0.8.2.2/logs
```

This folder has 14 months data. I want to delete last year's data from (logs). Will this cause any problems?  Do i need to stop kafka or can i disable last years logs while it is running?
how do i disable/reduce logging to this folder?

Answer (score 0):

There is log4j file in the config folder of the broker which you need to reconfigure as per your needs and then do a rolling bounce of the brokers if you don't need the down time for the cluster and then delete the older logs

Answer (score 0):

You can delete those logs as they are application event logging. These are only needed when something is fishy and you need to debug the issue.